# PHP multiple comparison conditions in one line

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I have this definition of a string:

```
$string = $string1 .' / '.$string2.' / '.$string3;
```

Is it possible to write in one line conditions for all strings if they not exists, write "0"?

```
if (!string1) {$string1="0";}
if (!string2) {$string2="0";}
if (!string3) {$string3="0";}
```

I tried something like:

```
$string = !$string1 ? "0" : $string1.' / '.!$string2 ? "0" : $string2.' / '.!$string3 ? "0": $string3;
```

but this way it is not working.

I also tried it with ?? :

```
$string = $string1 ?? "0" .' / '.$string2 ?? "0" .' / '.$string3 ?? "0";
```

Comment: If they don't exist as in they aren't declared?

Comment: yes, in that case I need to display "0". And I don't want to define them at start as "0", I need to solve it in that line

Comment: Can you please define "not working"? Do you get an error, incorrect result, etc. What version of PHP are you using. For ternary you need to group the expressions, it also is unreadable and advised against in the PHP manual (`It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious`)

Comment: `($string1 ?? 0) .'/'. ($string2 ?? 0). '/'. ($string3 ??0)`

Comment: excellent! i just missed the parenthesis, now it is working this way ($string1 ?? 0) .'/'. ($string2 ?? 0). '/'. ($string3 ?? 0). Thank you @nice_dev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last attempt was very close but your use of the ternary operator needs parenthesis around each of the tests for it to work.

```
$string = ($string1 ?? "0") .' / '. ($string2 ?? "0") .' / '. ($string3 ?? "0");
```

Comment: yes, this way with parenthesis it finally work as nice_dev suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do this both ways

I have done small changes, your both statements are working after adding round brackets.

```
$string = (!$string1 ? "0" : $string1).' / '.(!$string2 ? "0" : $string2).' / '.(!$string3 ? "0": $string3);
```

```
$string = ($string1 ?? "0") .' / '. ($string2 ?? "0") .' / '. ($string3 ?? "0");
```